# Trouble selecting controls in Rider WinForms designer

Tags: winforms, rider

**Unimportant background**

I'm currently using Visual Studio for developing .NET WinForms applications both at work and privately. I have used ReSharper for years, and would probably have a hard time managing without it, but I only just recently decided to take a look at Rider (to possibly replace Visual Studio).

I have now tested Rider with a bunch of my old VS projects, and found that I like it a lot. No significant problems detected so far, except for the problem described below.

Since pretty much every project I work on involves WinForms design, this problem is a real deal-breaker for me. So I'm hoping that there is a simple solution that I have missed.

**The problem**

Many of my forms contains nested controls, sometimes several layers deep - like a bunch of controls in a TableLayoutPanel in a SplitContainer, in another SplitContainer, and so on.

In the Forms Designer in Visual Studio, I can select the control I want to work with from the drop-down list at the top of the Properties window. Or if I right-click anywhere in the designer, the context menu will contain a "select control" option for every control that is under the mouse cursor.

The forms designer in Rider does not seem to have any such functionality - or at least I cannot find it. As far as I can tell, the only way to select a control is to click on it in the designer window. That works fine for visible controls like a TextBox, but nested layout controls are much harder to get a hold of (some seems impossible).

Am I missing something here? Is there an easy way to select *any* control in the designer? Or is there some plugin that can help with this, or at least a good-enough workaround?

The only "tip" i have managed to find so far is to *not* use the designer at all. That is, to write the GUI code by hand. That is not an option for me.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-26661 Already tracked but not yet being worked on.

Comment: @LexLi, thank you. I dug a little deeper there myself after posting, and found other similar tickets. I upvoted [RIDER-25764](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-25764#focus=Comments-27-5072611.0-0) (link to my comment to it) which contains a different approach to solving the problem - probably easier to implement and thereby perhaps more likely to get done.